# What's the purpose of base64.standard_b64decode(s)?

Tags: python

It seems to be identical to `base64.b64decode(s)` except it doesn't have the option to take an additional argument. Why would someone need the "standard_" version when they can just use the normal version and leave out the second argument?

Answer (score 5):

The first can use an optional alphabet, and revert to the standard if none is given; the other uses the standard.
It is possible that the API has both methods for backwards compatibility (to avoid breaking existing code)

[**From the documentation:**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)

> **base64.b64encode(s, altchars=None)**
>   Encode the bytes-like object s
>   using Base64 and return the encoded bytes.
>        Optional altchars must be a bytes-like object of at least length 2 (additional characters are ignored) which specifies an alternative
>   alphabet for the + and / characters. This allows an application to
>   e.g. generate URL or filesystem safe Base64 strings. The default is
>   None, for which the standard Base64 alphabet is used.

---

> **base64.standard_b64encode(s)**   Encode bytes-like object s using the standard Base64 alphabet and return the encoded bytes.